# Pass preprocessor definition to clang++

Tags: clang++, preprocessor-directive

Given

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0;
    #ifdef MACRO_A
         // custom behaviour
    #endif
    // program code
}
```

Is it possible to pass `#define MACRO_A` to clang++ when compiling to allow the 'custom behavour' statements to come into effect?  I cannot find documentation which suggests this is possible in clang++, but it IS possible in other compilers (g++).

Comment: From clang++ man page:
`-D<macroname>=<value>
              Adds an implicit #define into the predefines buffer which is read before the source file is preprocessed.`

Comment: @pevasquez Thankyou, that's doing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command, thanks to pevasquez's help, is

```
clang++ -D MACRO_A main.cpp -o main
```

The function

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0;
    #ifdef MACRO_A
         // custom behaviour
    #endif
    // program code
}
```

will compile with the code in the pre-processor directive section being included.

This will be an addition to my makefiles to create a debug friendly make-chain as well and the production version.